# buffer overflow when moving an element to an empty vector

Tags: c++, vector, buffer-overflow

Hello I am trying to move one element from the `game_cards` vector to the `hand` vector.
`game_cards` has 20 objects.
But when I run my code I get a bufferoverflow even though I am just moving one element.
I think the function `hand_out_card` is correct.
Am I missing something?
Thank you in advance

Gamer.hpp:

```
std::vector<Cards *> hand; 

void hand_out_card(std::vector <Card*> &hand_cards){


            Card* c = hand_cards.back();
            hand_cards.pop_back();
            hand.push_back(c);


 }
```

Main.cpp:

```
std::vector<Cards *> game_cards; // has 20 card* objects

Player objects;
object.hand_out_card(&game_cards); // here I get a bufferoverflow
```

I expected hand to have one element  of `game_cards` , why am I getting a bufferoverlow even though I am just moving one element?

Comment: `object.hand_out_card(&game_cards);` should give a compilation error. Also it causes undefined behaviour if you have that header file included by two .cpp files, due to multiple definitions

Comment: It would improve the question to include a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: What is a "bufferoverflow"? Please include error messages verbatim in the question.

Comment: You have a bug, and nothing in the posted code justifies the claim that `game_cards` has 20 `Card*` objects. Maybe you are wrong about that? If `game_cards` is empty then you'd get an error calling `hand_out_card`. Of course I don't know for sure, but it fits the evidence you've presented.